# How to use external certificate for HTTPS in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

my nodejs server currently uses a self-signed certificate as follows:

```
var sslOptions = {
                key: fs.readFileSync('./self-ssl/server.key'),
                cert: fs.readFileSync('./self-ssl/server.crt'),
                ca: fs.readFileSync('./self-ssl/ca.crt'),
                requestCert: true,
                rejectUnauthorized: false
        };
        https = require('https').createServer(sslOptions, app);
```

I want to change this to use a 3rd party certificate, I have received a RapidSSL certificate for my domain which is copied in `./ssl/mactester_com_ee.crt`.

My question is how do I edit the old self-signed code to use the new 3rd party certificate?

Thanks,

Comment: You need the key and ca certificate. Usually if you get a certificate store file you can use OpenSSL to export each

Comment: seems to work without the ca certificate see my answer below.

Comment: If it's a public ca then it may already be in your certificate store

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
var sslOptions = {
                key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server_private.key'),
                cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/3rdparty.crt'),
        };
https = require('https').createServer(sslOptions, app);
```